# Parsing XML with minidom

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm struggling with minidom. I need to locate an entry in the dom, update the text it holds, and then save the file. So far, the only way I've successfully been able to do locate the particular element is through a very explicit, direct, hard-coded method:

```
doc.childNodes[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[5].childNodes[11].childNodes[1].childNodes[3]
```

I just want to update the first `<text>` in `<typeBox type="counter">`.

```
<typeBoxes>
    <typeBox type="counter">
        <text fontSize="140">123456</text>
        <text fontSize="26">Foobar</text>
        <incrementTextFieldNum>1</incrementTextFieldNum>
        <timing>1</timing>
        <increment>1</increment>
    </typeBox>
    <typeBox>
        <image>images/foo.png</image>
        <text fontSize="26">Foo</text>-->
    </typeBox>

    ...
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What are you able to find normally? Can you find the `typeBox` element? Can you get a list of the `text` elements? Show us the code for how far you got.

Comment: Well I was able to access it a little better with doc.getElementsByTagName('typeBox')[0].childNodes[1], but even this is still hard-coded indicies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

minidom is not very powerful, most folks are using some variation of ElementTree these days.  Python2.5 and later has it built in.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
>>> corpus = """<typeBoxes>
...     <typeBox type="counter">
...         <text fontSize="140">123456</text>
...         <text fontSize="26">Foobar</text>
...         <incrementTextFieldNum>1</incrementTextFieldNum>
...         <timing>1</timing>
...         <increment>1</increment>
...     </typeBox>
...     <typeBox>
...         <image>images/foo.png</image>
...         <text fontSize="26">Foo</text>-->
...     </typeBox>
... </typeBoxes>"""
>>> 
>>> doc = etree.fromstring(corpus)
>>> 
>>> for typeBox in doc.findall('typeBox'):
...     if typeBox.attrib.get('type') == 'counter':
...         fieldnum = int(typeBox.find('incrementTextFieldNum').text)
...         incr = int(typeBox.find('increment').text)
...         text_field = typeBox.findall('text')[fieldnum-1]
...         text_field.text = str(int(text_field.text) + incr)
... 
>>> print etree.tostring(doc)
<typeBoxes>
    <typeBox type="counter">
        <text fontSize="140">123457</text>
        <text fontSize="26">Foobar</text>
        <incrementTextFieldNum>1</incrementTextFieldNum>
        <timing>1</timing>
        <increment>1</increment>
    </typeBox>
    <typeBox>
        <image>images/foo.png</image>
        <text fontSize="26">Foo</text>--&gt;
    </typeBox>
</typeBoxes>
>>>
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, doc.findall('typeBox') doesn't find anything

Comment: is the root node of the document you're parsing really a `<typeBoxes>`?  if it's something else, you might need to first traverse to that node.

Comment: No it isn't, it's <stories> <wall> <wallBoxes> <typeBoxes>.

Comment: Ah yes, >>> e.getroot()
<Element 'typeBoxes' at 0x101d00910>
>>> e.findall('typeBox')
[<Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00950>, <Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00b10>, <Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00b90>, <Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00c10>, <Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00c90>, <Element 'typeBox' at 0x101d00d50>]

Comment: There is no problem doing the same thing with minidom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first item in a `childNodes` list, try using:

```
typeBox_node = next((node for node in typeBoxs_node.childNodes \
                              if node.localName == 'typeBox'))
```

If you want to do it for each one of some element, try:

```
for typeBox_node in doc.getElementsByTagName('typeBox'):
    text_node = next((node for node in typeBox_node.childNodes \
                              if node.localName == 'text'))
```